# Qt application losing input after re-plugging input device

Tags: linux, qt, qml, qtquick2

This is pretty straightforward. I'm running a basic QML application in Linux.
When I unplug and replug my keyboard, I lose input in QML.

I see that a new `/dev/input` device is created so, I guess, Qt is looking for the old one.

Is there any way to tell Qt to use any `/dev/input` device it can see?

---

**Edit:** I've opened bug report about it, here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48000

Comment: Sounds like something that should work. It works for me on Windows. I'd create a bug report if I were you (with a minimal example, Qt version, environment details, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I never knew that it's working somewhere.

Comment: @10robinho: Hi, I am facing similar flavor of the issue with my keyboard and also I have seen your QT BUG that you created. Am not sure if you ever find a solution to this, my problem is little different though I have my question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586149/qt-could-not-read-from-input-device-no-such-device 
any help on this is appreciated thanks.

Comment: @user12345 it's simple - use udev which will help you dynamically crate input devices on replug.